# Why do we need to earn reputation to be able to do certain things?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, privileges

I really want to ask some questions and include pictures in them, but why does Stack Overflow require this thing called reputation in order to be able to do that?

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user (as soon as you get 10 rep : you will have less restrictions.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: It's certainly within the realm of conception that a user with edit privs will come along, see your question, decide images you link to are needed and good for your question, and edit them in. I've done it before.

Comment: I believe new users *can* include images by using the `![]()` syntax.

Comment: On your asking questions: based on your one, I'd suggest you to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A huge part of what makes Stack Overflow a good site to ask questions on is that we have a bar for quality. Don't sweat; it's about as low as the reputation-linked privileges, that is, it only requires minimal effort from your side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are small reputation barriers in place for posting images and comments on other people's posts to prevent spammers from getting the upper hand.

Spammers usually don't put much effort into their puppet accounts and very rarely (if ever) do spam accounts have more than 1 rep. The only thing 1-rep users can do is post questions and answers – when spam is posted as questions or answers, it's much easier to get rid of, and the process is also quite fast.

These barriers also prevent spammers [and/or trolls](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290775/why-do-we-need-to-earn-reputation-to-be-able-to-do-certain-things/290776#comment179262_290776) from posting spammy and/or inappropriate images.

The barrier is fairly low (relatively speaking, of course). If you ask a well-received question or two, or suggest a few good edits, you'll have enough reputation to post pictures in no time.

Comment: As an added bonus, by the time you *can* post pictures, there's a better chance you know to *avoid relying* on pictures wherever possible.

Comment: But for now just post a link to your image - then a reviewer with the required rep will be able to edit the image into the post if appropriate.

Comment: For images, I think the reputation barrier might be in place more for trolls, who otherwise would be able to post horrifying or obscene images all over the site. I've seen quite a few of them try to do this.

Comment: @BradLarson I forgot about that – thanks.

Comment: @Deduplicator If only that were true... it's unfortunately not.

Comment: @nhgrif: Well, I only said a better chance, not a good chance.

Comment: Fair enough....